# Regular expression to extract entire text between parent tags based on child tag values

Tags: regex

I have a text file with data like below.

```
<message>
<tag1>1</tag1>
<tag2>Car</tag2>
</message>#@#
<message>
<tag1>2</tag1>
<tag2>Bus</tag2>
</message>#@#
<message>
<tag1>3</tag1>
<tag2>Car</tag2>
</message>#@#
<message>
<tag1>4</tag1>
<tag2>Truck</tag2>
</message>
```

I need to extract all message which has child tag which matches a given value Ex: Car. As shown below. Any hep is much

```
<message>
<tag1>1</tag1>
<tag2>Car</tag2>
</message>
<message>
<tag1>3</tag1>
<tag2>Car</tag2>
</message>
```

I tried below but it is returning wrong data as given below. Any help is much appreciated,

```
<message>[\s\S]*?<tag2>Car<\/tag2>[\s\S]*?<\/message>


<message>
<tag1>1</tag1>
<tag2>Car</tag2>
</message>#@#
<message>
<tag1>2</tag1>
<tag2>Bus</tag2>
</message>#@#
<message>
<tag1>3</tag1>
<tag2>Car</tag2>
</message>
```

Comment: See [tag:regex] tag rules: always specify which engine you are working with, as regex dialects differ. The main problem in your regex is the fact that `.` does not by default include the newline character; but the way to toggle this option differs from engine to engine. (Also, obligatory "not a job for regex")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
<message>\n.*\n.*?Car.*?\n<\/message>
```

[Demo URL](https://regex101.com/r/6KDZmT/2)